# Padrão BEM no CSS

Tags: css, bem

Estou utilizando o padrão BEM e me veio uma dúvida, quando tenho um elemento com filhos e netos, como devo nomear minhas classes?

Vou usar código para dar esse exemplo:

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__container">
    <!-- BURGUER MOBILE MENU -->
    <div class="header__burguer">
      <img class="??????" src="burguer.png" alt="Menu Mobile">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

A parte da imagem dentro do `header__burguer` que esta me confundindo,

se eu usar `header__img` ficaria meio sem nexo, pois img é genérico demais e utilizar 4 underscores acho que sai do padrão do BEM. `header__burguer__img`

Alguém poderia sugerir algo de acordo com esse padrão? Procurando, ainda não achei nada.

Comment: Isso é um sinal claro que está deixando o seu elemento mais complexo do que deveria. Se eu criar um botão "hamburguer" no header e outro no footer, qual serão as diferenças? O botão precisa, realmente, depender de header?

Comment: No caso, não depende. Em minha concepção eu coloco o header_burguer porque esse elemento está dentro do header. Com sua resposta vejo isso que eu tinha entendido então não tem nada a ver, certo?

Comment: Correto. Você utiliza o BEM para apenas o seu elemento isolado. Por definição ele não pode depender do contexto que for inserido.

Comment: na verdade no footer seria algo como `<footer class="footer">...
  <div class="footer__ burguer">`

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa resposta, e principalmente nos dois links que cito lá no finalzinho https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/412137/como-n%c3%a3o-repetir-c%c3%b3digo-css/412151#412151

Comment: @hugocsl obrigado mas agora me confundiu um pouco novamente kkk. Por exemplo, mesmo lance do Header, agora no footer, imagina que dentro do footer__ burguer eu tenha uma imagem, como eu nomearia a <img> sendo que não posso usar 4 underscores como está no padrão do BEM, ou seja, footer__burguer__img

Comment: Sei que a pergunta é da parte técnica, mas tá ai uma questão, inventaram o BEM para ajudar a "corrigir" problemas que nem deveriam existir e me parece que as pessoas adotam coisas assim (não só BEM e não só no CSS) como se fosse a verdade única que vai lhes salvar de todos os problemas. Eu uso CSS a anos, procurei praticar e entender muito bem os seletores e regras (rules) e me organizei bem (bem de verdade, não BEM) e nunca tive problemas, até recebia elogios pelos meus CSS minimalistas que apresentavam o mesmo resultado e muitas vezes bem mais leves...

Comment: ... O BEM por si só é escrever um monte de coisas, até mais que o normal de forma supostamente organizada, e no final você terá bem mais coisas do que o esperado e talvez até se perca na suposta organização. Vou resumir, aprender os rules e praticar me parece muito mais vantajoso, a maioria afirma que sabem CSS, mas só sabem o minimo do básico e por isso acabam acreditando em supostas soluções e "receitas de bolo"... Não é uma critica a ti, é uma critica "aos padrões" (em diversos lugares e linguagens) que as vezes são problemas disfarçados de "solução"

Comment: Obrigado pelos conselhos, @GuilhermeNascimento!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é um jeito de escrever BEM mais do que precisa para chegar no resultado,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parte da *filosofia* de nomenclatura definida pelo BEM é que um componente do site não deve depender do seu contexto. Se a exibição do componente muda conforme o contexto, será o CSS que definirá isso com as regras específicas para tal, porém para a construção do próprio componente deverá ser independente.

Para um botão de menu do tipo hambúrguer, como colocado na pergunta, ele não deveria depender se está no header ou em qualquer outro lugar da página. Em outras palavras, não é responsabilidade do botão saber das informações do cabeçalho, então as classes  não devem se misturar.

Assim, um possível componente seria:

```
<div class="hamburguer">
  <span class="hamburguer__line"></span>
  <span class="hamburguer__line"></span>
  <span class="hamburguer__line"></span>
</div>
```

Onde você conseguiria estilizado independente do contexto. Ao pressionar o elemento, para alterar a visualização, você poderia adicionar a classe modificadora através de JS.

```
<div class="hamburguer hamburguer--opened">
  <span class="hamburguer__line"></span>
  <span class="hamburguer__line"></span>
  <span class="hamburguer__line"></span>
</div>
```

Ao inserir o seu componente no cabeçalho, ficaria algo como:

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="header__container">
    <div class="hamburguer">
      <span class="hamburguer__line"></span>
      <span class="hamburguer__line"></span>
      <span class="hamburguer__line"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```